# How to get the output of running mathematica after loosing the interface?

Tags: notebooks, user-interface

I was running a mathematica code in cluster using notebook interface by remote login. Suddenly, the internet got down and I lost the connection. Also the notebook interface is lost. After getting the renewed connection I have checked that the code is running. But the problem is how can I get my results now? I have written a code in a single cell and four tables are to be formed. If I had the interface I could export them to get the data files. Now what to do?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Wolfram Support, or your cluster admins? It's hard to say from here.